# A 'Missing draft message' 401 error while trying to create a draft

Tags: axios, request, gmail, gmail-api

While trying to `POST` at `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${user_id}/drafts`, in order to create a gmail draft, I get prompt with a `Missing draft message` error.

This is the actual code that make the request:

```js
let userMail = axios.post(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${user_id}/drafts`,
  {
    body: {
      draft: {
        message: {
          raw: "Hard Coded mail",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    }
  })
  console.log(userMail)
```

The `console.log(userMail)` show's a bunch of information such as:

```json
data: {
      error: {
        code: 400,
        message: 'Missing draft message',
        errors: [
          {
            message: 'Missing draft message',
            domain: 'global',
            reason: 'invalidArgument'
          }
        ],
        status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'
      }
}
```

Am I missing on something in the `body` of the request, or is the syntax incorrect ?

According to this thread [Missing draft message - javascript Gmail API - how to structure body of the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077023/missing-draft-message-javascript-gmail-api-how-to-structure-body-of-the-requ),

> "The correct structure of the request:"

```json
'draft': {
  'message': {
    'raw': base64EncodedEmail
  }
}
```

**PS:** I'm not using external node modules, keeping it "vanilla"

**EDIT (1):**
Trying to add `From`, `To` and `Subject` fields:

```js
var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
  'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
  'From: ' + from + "\r\n" +
  'To: ' + to + "\r\n" +
  'Subject: ' + subject + "\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
  'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
  mailContent + "\r\n\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary--';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, the request body is `JSON.stringify({"message": {"raw": data}})`.
- Please include `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in the request header.
- When you want to put a text of `Hard Coded mail`, please create the request body as follows.

  ```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary

    --boundaryboundary
    Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Hard Coded mail

    --boundaryboundary--
  ```
- And, please encode the above request body to the websafe-base64 data.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
var user_id = "me";
var text = "Hard Coded mail";

var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
  'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
  '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
  'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
  text + "\r\n\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary--';
var blob = new Blob([message], {type:"text/plain"});
var f = new FileReader();
f.readAsDataURL(blob);
f.onload = d => {
  var base64 = d.target.result.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+').split(",")[1];
  axios.post(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${user_id}/drafts`,
    JSON.stringify({"message": {"raw": base64}}),
    {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`, "Content-Type": "application/json"}}
  ).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.response.data.error)
  })
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is shown in the log.

```json
{
   "id":"###",
   "message":{
      "id":"###",
      "threadId":"###",
      "labelIds":[
         "DRAFT"
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.drafts.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create)

### Added:

As another method, how about the following modified script? In this modification, `blob` is not used. And the content type of `message/rfc822` is used. And in this case, the endpoint is changed to `https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/${user_id}/drafts`. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script:

```js
var user_id = "me";
var text = "Hard Coded mail";

var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
  'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
  '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
  'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
  text + "\r\n\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary--';
axios.post(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/${user_id}/drafts`,
  message,
  {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`, "Content-Type": "message/rfc822"}}
).then((res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error.response.data.error)
})
```

Comment: Thnks for the detailed and step by step answer. Though I'm still going through an issue with the ```new Blob(...)``` that is ```not a constructor (TypeError)```. I've tried adding the following require as suggested in a few SO an GH threads, but nothing successful.
```const Blob = require('buffer')```

Comment: @HCKRMVT Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? In that case, the endpoint is changed and the blob is not used.

Comment: Thank you in the first place, no worries ! And indeed it works, the log I get is the same as you show in the **Result** and after checking, a new mail appears in my draft inbox.

Comment: @HCKRMVT Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: do the new fields in the message I've added to 'EDIT(1)' message seem correct to you ? I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310846/10648704) thread to bring these modifications, but ultimately they don't show up in my gmail draft.

Comment: @HCKRMVT I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, if my proposed script was not useful, I have to apologize.